# How do I uninstall Java ME SDK from Windows 7 x64?

Tags: java-me, uninstallation

I try to uninstall Java ME SDK from Windows 7 x64, but it doesn't work for me.

If I choose `Uninstall` I get a progress bar, then it goes away, but the Software is still there.

On the first few times I did this, I got the same error message as in [I need help UNINSTALLING Java ME SDK](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=9260094):

```
... show message dialog
title: Critical Error
message: Cannot load native library from path: native/jmesdk/windows/windows-x86.dll

Exception:
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Temp\nbi-8367277139934329064.tmp: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the exact same problem and I figured it out. :)

It's because you have the 64-bit JRE installed. Either uninstall it or somehow redirect the J2ME uninstaller to use the 32-bit JRE on your system, so that the 32-bit uninstaller can run instead of the 64-bit uninstaller.

Comment: How can I do this? Please help me. I have the same problem. Windows 7 64 bit and installed J2ME SDK 3.0 and it does not works and also can not uninstall it. Thanks!!

Comment: @JeanPaul: Did you remove the 64-bit JRE?

Comment: yes. Confirming, Only after uninstallation of the Jdk 8 I was able to uninstall that J2me 32 bit sdk. The JDK 7 was nt touched.

Answer (score 7):

In ref to getting the uninstaller to use the 32-bit JRE, the config I attempted that failed to work:

a) Set the PATH environmental variable to point to the 32-bit JRE
b) Windows registry edits in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\1.6 to point to the 32-bit JRE.

In a last ditch effort I renamed \Program Files\Java to Java2, and the uninstaller must have searched to find \Program Files (x86)\Java, the 32-bit JRE, and the uninstall worked.

Seriously, Sun/Oracle.  Test your products.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and figured the solution out. As mentioned above you need to make sure J2ME unnistaller only recognizes Java x86. The simplest way I found, instead of unnistalling Java x64, you only have to temporarily rename your Java x64 installation folder to anything you want. That is, rename the folder C:\Program Files\Java to, e.g, C:\Program Files\JavaTEMP.

Now run unnistaller. When finished rename the folder back it's previous name.
That's all.

Hope I helped.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had exactly the same problem, uninstall java (TM) 7 64bit and locate the 32-bit java installer bone this [download](http://sdlc-esd.sun.com/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/7u5-b06/jre-7u5-windows-i586.exe?AuthParam=1345043358_bf912189055c758804a86c5d621d3689&GroupName=JSC&FilePath=/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/7u5-b06/jre-7u5-windows-i586.exe&File=jre-7u5-windows-i586.exe&BHost=javadl.sun.com) uninstall it and try to install the Sun Java Wireless Toolkit and uninstalled correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Just perform the following steps and you will be done:

1) Click on the link below and click on any of the ...**i586.exe** link according to your system
   http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html

2)Install the software without changing default settings.

3)Run cmd command and type the following:

```
C:\Java_ME_platform_SDK_3.0\uninstall.exe --javahome "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre8"
```

4)[optional] uninstall java 8 from control panel which you downloaded to uninstall the above software.

Congratulations.. You just did it!!

Thank you for reading.. Any suggestions or aprreciation is welcomed..

Answer (score 0):

Just run this command:
C:\Java_ME_platform_SDK_3.0\uninstall.exe --javahome "32-bit jre location"

Answer (score -1):

Rather than temporarily moving the x64 JRE out of the way, just tell the J2ME SDK uninstaller to use the 32bit JRE:

```
C:\Java_ME_platform_SDK_3.0\uninstall.exe --javahome "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7"
```

Note that this provides the path to a JRE within the "Program Files (x86)" directory, which is the 32bit variant. I only had a Java 7 JRE, but this ought to work with a Java 6 JRE, also.

Comment: Can you please Explain you answer so it would help others to understand.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Hi, it absolutely does answer the question. The generally accepted approach here seems to be to move the x64 JRE out of the way or to make registry/ path changes, both of which are hacks. The accepted answer mentions "redirecting" the uninstaller to use the x86 JRE, but doesn't give any information as to how to do this. My post actually gives the exact command to perform the uninstallation without messing with the Java environment, yet it gets down-voted? Interesting. I found this topic whilst trying to uninstall the J2ME 3.0 SDK myself and thought I'd share the solution to help others.

Comment: Additionally, I don't have enough "reputation" to comment on the actual answer to improve it (as you allude to), something which the kindness of your down-vote hasn't helped with. I also have a job and personal (software development) projects, so can't spend all of my time earning the requisite reputation to be able to provide random altruistic assistance beyond what I had already posted. Thanks for damaging the good intentions of those who do actually wish to contribute.